# Button not showing up after "unhiding" it

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, uibutton

Hey everyone - I cant seem to figure out what i am doing wrong here. I create a button in my rootviewcontroller. I immediately hide it, when my parser is done that was started on a seperate thread I send it to a method that "unhides" my button. But... its not "unhiding" it.

Here is what i have in my ViewDidLoad of my RootViewController

```
 showtimesButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
 image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"homeshowtimes.png"];
 [showtimesButton setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 showtimesButton.frame = CGRectMake(27, 390, 265, 63);
 [showtimesButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showtimesButtonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
 [self.view addSubview:showtimesButton];
 showtimesButton.hidden = YES;
```

and here is the method that is "unhiding" it. I put a break in this method so i know i am getting to it.

```
-(void)unhideShowtimesButton {

 showtimesButton.hidden = NO;


}
```

any thoughts? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you're calling `unhideShowtimesButton` on the main thread:

```
[anObject performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(unhideShowtimesButton) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

Where `anObject` is the object you're doing the parsing in, if it's in the same object at the button, use `self`

You can't interact with UI elements on anything other than the main thread.

Comment: Hmm... still not able to pull it off. I will have to try again here in a minute when I get a little more free time to mess with it. Thanks for the post!